# Video starts 9 seconds in on VLC media player

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-playback

I'm working on chopping up a video with VLC. One of the snippets that I have recorded starts at 9 seconds when I try to play it with VLC. My project is recording these snippets, and then converting them to MP3's. I'm doing all of this with VLC. The problem is, the MP3 recordings are also affected.

Note, the whole recording is there, including the first 9 seconds, but for some reason VLC wants to start the video in the wrong spot when it plays it and when it converts it. An ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does the video start from the beginning from another media player? Can you scrub back from the beginning using VLC?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Yes and yes.

Comment: What happens when you reinstall VLC?

Comment: I have reinstalled VLC, and I re-recorded, but now VLC is playing it from the start (yay!) but there is no audio this time around. There is audio when I play it with WMP

Comment: Is the audio Stereo? Surround?

Comment: The audio is stereo

Comment: Are the recorded snippets saved in AAC? MP4?

Comment: The recording functionality in VLC seems to output them into .ts video files

Comment: Open the `Control Panel`. Click on `Hardware and Sound`. Click `Sound`. Click on your speakers that you want to hear the sound from. Click `Properties`. Click on the 'Enhancements' tab. Click on `Disable all enhancements`. There may be a small chance that reinstalling VLC caused something to change in your speaker settings.

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything.